# Windows can not see partitions but acronis sees

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, acronis-diskdirector

I've installed dual boot(Ubuntu and Windows) to my SSD. I've 2 disks:

1. SSD (~240GB)
2. HDD (~1TB)

Windows can see only one partition on HDD. Ubuntu can see 2 partitions. But there are 3 partitions. Here is what windows see:

[image]

And this is the acronis disk director:
[image]

I want to recover Disk 2(HDD) **Data** Partition. Acronis sees the files by right click and *Browse Files*. I've tried to right click and *Check*, but it doesn't perform and gives this error: `Can not perform the operation on the selected volume because the volume is unavailable for the current operating system.`

My question is:

1. Can I fix this disk, so windows can see it and I don't lost my data in HDD.

Comment: Did you fully shutdown Linux before booting Windows, as that can occur when the partition is still marked in use by another OS to prevent data corruption? Does `DiskPart` or Disk Management [`diskmgmt.msc`] see the partition? If so, use either to mount it and run a `chkdsk /offlinescanandfix`

Comment: What version of Windows is this?

Comment: @JW0914 Disk Management sees the entire disk, not partitions as Dynamic and Invalid. Diskpart sees the disks and partitions. I've shutdown the Linux.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Wİndows 10

Comment: And where would Ubuntu have been installe?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille On Acronis screenshot, disk 1(SSD). Can't see it because it's ext4 filesystem

Comment: Yes, you said that in your question, but which partition?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille in "Data Partition" as "not formatted"

Comment: Is it normal that the Acronis sees Data as two parts? Because I've tried to change the letter one of them and it changes two parts

Comment: With Acronis, it seems you could merge these partitions, since they are adjacent.

Comment: Can you check this: https://forum.acronis.com/forum/acronis-disk-director-forum/cant-see-spanned-3tb-drive-after-win10-upgrade

Comment: You would have to install a driver for whatever file system you had used for the partition.  Windows by default cannot access ext4 partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not want to access to ext4 partition, I want to access my NTFS partition

Comment: @sundowatch - Except "Data Partition" is not NTFS which is the partition you said you wanted to mount within Windows.  It either has no file system or is ext4.

Comment: I think that would be about, formatting the unlocated disk in Linux. It has assigned the letter as D. And that may be a conflict

Answer (score 0):

I've boot to Ubuntu and deleted the partition which I have created on Ubuntu. Then reboot to Windows and disks have seen now.

It may be a conflict when creating an NTFS drive on Linux.

Comment: Most people do not use Linux when they want to create an NTFS drive.  It may have changed recently, but NTFS was proprietary.  Even writing to it from Linux needed specific drivers.

Comment: You're right, my way was too weird, but I've wanted to use it on Windows and understand now it was the wrong way

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - NTFS support within Linux has been stable for over a decade.

Comment: @Ramhound So, what went wrong in the OP's case?

Comment: If they created the NTFS partition that might have something to do with it but more than likely the entire problem is the spanned partition.